# How can I use "?" in teradata so that I am prompted to put in new data each time I run the query?

Tags: teradata

I'm using the below query in access to build a database. I want to use this query with different date ranges and a different "ndc" number. In the below query I used question marks but do not get results. I know I can use ? in Sql server, but teradata is not accepted the ambiguity. Can i do this somehow rather than having to specify the date range and the "ndc" number?

```
 select ls.str_nbr, ndc11, wic_nbr, prod_name, pkg_sz, pkg_qty, count(*) as rx_volume, sum(fill_qty_dspn), sum(fill_gross_profit_dlrs), sum(fill_revenue_dlrs), sum(fill_cost_dlrs)     
    from (select * from prdedwvwh.prescription_fill_sold where fill_sold_dt Between ? And ? ) as pf           
    inner join  
                    prdedwvwh.prescription_fill_sales_metric pfsm
    on            
    pf.str_nbr=pfsm.str_nbr and     
    pf.rx_nbr=pfsm.rx_nbr and       
    pf.rx_fill_nbr= pfsm.rx_fill_nbr and            
    pf.rx_partial_fill_nbr =pfsm.rx_partial_fill_nbr and      
    pf.fill_enter_dt=pfsm.fill_enter_dt and       
    pf.fill_sold_dt=pfsm.fill_sold_dt                 
    inner join  
                    prdedwvwh.drug_cur dd
    on            
                    pf.drug_id=dd.drug_id
    and ndc11 in ('?') 
    inner join  
                    prdedwvwh.location_store ls 
    on            
                    pf.str_nbr=ls.str_nbr 
    and ls.mail_retail_ind ='RETAIL'               

    group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: Try it without the single quotes around ?: `ndc11 in (?)`. With the single quotes, you are literally sending the ? as your constraint.  I'm not sure you can use a parameter marker for an in list though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your client tool to submit this query?

To be able to use it from any client you would need to us Dynamic SQL in a Stored Procedure or create a macro like:

```
    replace macro mymac(ndc integer, start_dt date, end_date date)
    as
    ( select ls.str_nbr, ndc11, wic_nbr, prod_name, pkg_sz, pkg_qty,
         count(*) as rx_volume, sum(fill_qty_dspn), sum(fill_gross_profit_dlrs),
         sum(fill_revenue_dlrs), sum(fill_cost_dlrs)     
      from (select * from prdedwvwh.prescription_fill_sold 
            where fill_sold_dt Between :start_dt And :end_dt ) as pf           
        inner join  
                        prdedwvwh.prescription_fill_sales_metric pfsm
        on            
        pf.str_nbr=pfsm.str_nbr and     
        pf.rx_nbr=pfsm.rx_nbr and       
        pf.rx_fill_nbr= pfsm.rx_fill_nbr and            
        pf.rx_partial_fill_nbr =pfsm.rx_partial_fill_nbr and      
        pf.fill_enter_dt=pfsm.fill_enter_dt and       
        pf.fill_sold_dt=pfsm.fill_sold_dt                 
        inner join  
                        prdedwvwh.drug_cur dd
        on            
                        pf.drug_id=dd.drug_id
        and ndc11 = :ndc
        inner join  
                        prdedwvwh.location_store ls 
        on            
                        pf.str_nbr=ls.str_nbr 
        and ls.mail_retail_ind ='RETAIL'               

        group by 1,2,3,4,5,6;  
    ) ;
```

But as Andrew already wrote, you can't pass multiple values within a single parameter (at least not in an easy way before TD14).

Comment: Thanks to both. I went a different wrote on this because you are right.